# Core Data Undeclared Type with Category/Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have tried the basic clean build and closing Xcode and hasn't cleared this issue.

I am trying to add in Core Data. I have my BadgeModel.xcdatamodeld file for Badge Entity set to Codegen Category/Extension
[Badge Entity Setup Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLK2.jpg)

Autogenerated properties
My error is here in the autogenerated file **Use of undeclared type 'Badge'**

```
//  Badge+CoreDataProperties.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Badge {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Badge> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Badge>(entityName: "Badge")
    }

    @NSManaged public var badgeDescription: String?
    @NSManaged public var dirtyDozen: Bool
    @NSManaged public var imageName: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var number: Int32
    @NSManaged public var selected: Bool
    @NSManaged public var statusValue: Int32
    @NSManaged public var value: Int32

}
```

and my extended Class

```
//  Badge+CoreDataClass.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Badge: NSManagedObject {
    enum Status: Int32 {
        case completed = 0
        case inProgress = 1
        case notPurchased = 2
    }
    var status: Status {
        get {
            return Status(rawValue: self.statusValue)!
        }
        set {
            self.statusValue = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }
    
    var iconImage: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
    
    var mainImage: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String, number: Int32 = 0, status: Status = .notPurchased, description: String, value: Int32, dirtyDozen: Bool = false, selected: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        let noSpaces = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        let okayChars : Set<Character> =
            Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")
        self.imageName = String(noSpaces.filter {okayChars.contains($0) })
        self.badgeDescription = description
        self.number = number
        self.value = value
        self.dirtyDozen = dirtyDozen
        self.selected = selected
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally tell the codgen to use a different module? Show the entity inspector please. Let us see your real codegen settings. Thanks

Comment: @matt added screenshot to post

Comment: Well I can't explain it but I can't reproduce it either. Your codegen and code works fine for me. Are you sure you want to build for Generic iOS Device? Not some specific device? Not that I expect that to fix it.

Comment: @matt going to scratch the work and go try it again

Comment: I redid the core data and it works now as expected. I believe when I created the subclass I deleted the properties file and this somehow broke my project. Instead I removed the reference rather than move the file to the trash.